# fill sortlist heart icon using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

i am using ajax to sort list the hotels when i click on heat icon which is coming from while query from database on that hear icon i called one function to set a session after set a session i want to fill heart icon without refreshing a page and again clicking on same heart icon i want to unset the particular id from session and show the heart icon as blank .
please provide me solution.
live url- https://www.hotelinkonkan.com

```
   <a class="clickforact"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" id="boricon1" onclick="cart('<?php echo $id;?>')" ></i> </a>


The Function which is write on this icon click event for add and remove the is from session 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
type:'post',
url:'./../include/store_items.php',
data:{
total_cart_items:"totalitems"
},
success:function(response) {
document.getElementById("total_items").value=response;
}
});
});
function cart(id)
{
$('.clickforact').click(function(){
if($(this).find($("i")).hasClass('fa-heart-o'))
{
$(this).find($("i")).removeClass('fa-heart-o').addClass('fa-heart');
}
else if($(this).find($("i")).hasClass('fa-heart'))
{
$(this).find($("i")).removeClass('fa-heart').addClass('fa-heart-o');    
}
});

$.ajax({
type:'post',
url:'./../include/store_items.php',
data:{
iteam_id:id
},
success:function(response) {
document.getElementById("total_items").value=response;
}
});
}
function cart_remove(id)
{
$.ajax({
type:'post',
url:'./../include/store_items.php',
data:{
iteam_id_remove:id
},
success:function(response) {
document.getElementById("total_items").value=response;
}
});
show_cart();
}
function show_cart()
{
$.ajax({
type:'post',
url:'./../include/store_items.php',
data:{
showcart:"cart"
},
success:function(response) {
document.getElementById("mycart").innerHTML=response;
$("#mycart").slideToggle();
}
});
}
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are calling event multiple times so you are facing an issue

1)with javascript 'onclick' : **onclick="cart('')"**

2)with jquery 'click' : **$('.clickforact').click(function(){}**

You can achive your goal using jquery only.
with  this:

```
 //pass data-id with anchor tag
    <a class="clickforact"  data-id="<?php echo $id;?>"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" id="boricon1"  ></i> </a>
```

Use only jquery event

```
$('.clickforact').click(function(){
if($(this).find($("i")).hasClass('fa-heart-o'))
{
$(this).find($("i")).removeClass('fa-heart-o').addClass('fa-heart');
}
else if($(this).find($("i")).hasClass('fa-heart'))
{
$(this).find($("i")).removeClass('fa-heart').addClass('fa-heart-o');    
}
var id = $(this).data("id"); //<---retrive your id
$.ajax({
type:'post',
url:'./../include/store_items.php',
data:{
iteam_id:id
},
success:function(response) {
document.getElementById("total_items").value=response;
}
});
});
```

Comment: sir the hotel listing is coming from another page from ajax using while loop in that image you will see 2 hotels for that destination when i click on 1st hotels heart icon it will filled but when i remove it on that click it cannot remove after click for twice then it removes that class because of while loop it working like this . only showing the filled box and unfilled box problem is there otherwise all i done in that . please provide the any other solution

Comment: Yes I told you this issue is because you are handling click with two methods. So method will conflict. Apply only single method. Have you tried this solution?